# Will this transistor setup work for powering a LED?

Tags: transistors

I think this should work but I would love for someone to confirm it to me. 
Transistors aren't really something I'm very familiar with.

Goal:
Power on D1750 (Orange LED) when VCC42 is low - Power off when VCC42 is high
Power on D1760 (Green LED) when VCC33 is high - Power off when VCC33 is low.

Basically an orange standby light and a green power on light.

Supplies:
VCC33_HOT: Always on supply, running when the power is plugged in - Created from a TPS62177 IC
VCC33: 3.3V Supply only running when the device is in an "ON" state - Created from a TPS62135 IC
VCC42: 4.2V Supply only running when the device is in an "ON" state - Created from a TPS62140 IC

Schematic:
[BC857](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1662680.pdf) (The transistor, T1)

My 'design':
[image: Schematic]

Thanks in advance, much appreciated!

Comment: I just realised as I completed my answer that the PMV160UP is a MOSFET but you've drawn a PNP BJT transistor.

Comment: Whoops, I swapped the design to use the BC857 but did not update the name of the transistor. Let me edit my post to include the right transistor! So sorry
- EDIT: Changed the transistor, but not the resistors as it would affect your answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The T1 circuit will work as expected *provided* that the transistor supply voltage is <= the base drive voltage. It is in your case so your circuit should be fine.

Here is an explanation of the trap that many fall into:

[image]

*Figure 1. The "high-side" switch fail. [Source](http://lednique.com/gpio-high-side-driver-fail/).*

- If If  \$ V_{SS}>V_{MICRO} \$ then the output protection diodes built into the chip provide a sneak path for the base current.
- The e-b junction of Q1 will be forward biased and current will flow through it, R1 and D1 to the micro supply.
- Q1 will turn on and LED will light and will not switch off.

Because your micro supply is 4.2 V and the transistor's emitter is at 3.3 V a high on the output will turn the transistor hard off.

---

**LED current**

[image]

*Figure 2. Resistance calculation. [Source](http://lednique.com/iv-curves/).*

Let's select a current of 5 mA for your LED. This is enough for most modern small LEDs to glow brightly. From Figure 2 we can see that at 5 mA an orange LED will drop about 1.65 V. Allowing about 0.3 V drop across your transistor that leaves 3 - 1.65 = 1.35 V across the current limiting resistor. From Ohm's law you can calculate the required value as \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {1.35}{5m} = 270 \ \Omega \$.

**Base resistor**

- The base resistor we can use the rough approximation of \$ I_c = h_{fe}I_b \$ where \$ I_c \$ is the collector current, \$ h_{fe} \$ is the transistor gain and \$ I_b \$ is the base current.
- The collector current is 5 mA and we can assume a gain of > 100 for a small signal transistor.
- From the above \$ I_b = \frac {I_c}{h_{fe}} = \frac {5m}{100} = 0.05\ \mathrm{mA} \$.
- A suitable base resistor is then \$ R = \frac {V}{I_b} = \frac {3}{0.05m} = 60 \ k\Omega \$. To be sure to drive the transistor fully into saturation most of us would pick a lower value to increase the base current. The transistor won't mind. 33 kΩ would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've updated the design to use a 33kΩ resistor as base resistor and moved R1755 for the LED down to 1.69kΩ to make it a little bit brighter and to take the small voltage drop of the transistor into consideration. (Unrelated but I also moved R1760 down to 1.8kΩ to increase the brightness of the power on LED). Also due a mistake I wrote PMV160UP (a mosfet) as the transistor while I meant BC857. I've updated it.    

Would this work? Thanks again: [Updated Schematic](https://i.imgur.com/z3qxF0p.png)

Comment: How did you arrive at 1.69 kΩ R1755? I have shown how to do the calculations.

Comment: I've selected 1.69kΩ based on my testing with the brightness I like. With the 3.3V supply directly connected to the LED with a 2kΩ resistor, I found the light to be about right, although it would be ok if it were to be slightly less. I took 200mV of voltage drop into consideration and calculated the right resistor to be 1.69kΩ. The standby light should be just bright enough to see if the user wants to verify their supply. I dislike standby lights that will lit up the room at night. I mistakenly took 3.3V into calculation (not thinking about the drop of the LED) and came to 4mA at first

Comment: That's fine then. As I mentioned in the post, many of the newer LEDs are quite bright at very low currents. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: No problem. You gave a clear explanation of what I needed and combined with some other resources learned some valuable information about transistors. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this will work! The "rest" of the circuit will bring the 4.2V line to 0V, turning on the LED (still, if you have a lot of bypass and bulk capacitance, this might take sometime, especially if the current consumption on the 4.2V line drops to the \$\mu A\$ range...).

Beware that the LED current will be quite small, only 0.5mA...

Furthermore the base resistor is unnecessarily small (it could be 10kOhm even with a 10x larger LED current).

**EDIT:**

Now I see another drawback of having a very small base resistor value: the VCC_3.3_HOT line might power the rest of the circuit, through the base-emitter junction and R1750 (this might cause problems if the circuitry connected to the 4.2V line work even at a much lower voltage -say 2.5V- and consume a very small current. For instance, if you have an LED connected between the 4.2V line and ground - with of course a resistor - then it could light up almost as bright as your orange LED!). You can use a pMOSFET.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you have any resources I can look into on how to select the proper value for the base resistor? Most resources I find online are written in a way its hard to understand unless you already know. Also how would I increase the LED current to somewhere between 2 to 4mA? Would I require a different transistor better suited for the job? Cheers :)

Comment: Hi Bart! I made some modifications, because I realized that the BJT might bring you into some troubles (read the edits!). How to calculate Rb: you want to bring the BJT in saturation, i.e. \$I_B > I_C/h_{FE}\$. (\$h_{FE}\$ is written in the datasheet). Some use the very strict (and in my opinion too much conservative) rule \$I_C < 10 \cdot I_B\$, regardless the gain. Personally I was taught of using the formula \$I_B > 2..5 \cdot I_C/h_{FE} \$, and found experimentally that it is a good rule of thunb, especially for signal BJTs. Your BJT will be ok.

Comment: To change the LED curent, simply reduce the R1755 value. The BJT in saturation will have a \$V_{CE,sat} = 0.2V\$. The orange LED will have a 2V forward voltage. Therefore the voltage on the resistor is 3.3 V - 0.2 V - 2V = 1.1V. Then use the Ohm's law, to set the current to about 4mA. For instance 270 Ohm. Signal LEDs typically can handle much more than 4mA (see the datasheet), e.g. 20mA.